# How to change member group from front end with Freemember

Tags: freemember

Let me know any one in Freemember how to update member group when update profile from front end.

if not possible in freemember then let me help for any other way for update member group from front end.

Thanks,
piyush

Comment: Do you mean on profile edit or on register?

Answer (score 1):

Freemember automatically unsets any posted `group_id` value, as it's a security risk for permissions-based sites. But, you could do this with an extension hook in Freemember - specifically the [freemember_update_member_start](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/blob/e38fe0766f11336d04d19a010ac8c5fbf6152491/system/expressionengine/third_party/freemember/models/freemember_model.php#L185) hook.

So post the `group_id` with a form name *other* than `group_id` (say, `new_group_id`), then in your extension, you could do something like this:

```
function freemember_update_member_start($member_id, $data)
{
    // Perform whatever checks you need to make sure that it's OK to change the member group for this update
    $data['group_id'] = ee()->input->post('new_group_id');
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply its help us when we want to group id changed by hook but we want to change group when login member want it means like update query we did that job by external entries addons http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/external-entries

Answer (score 0):

As gar as I'm aware, only SA can alter the group a member belongs to.

I'll keep an eye here to see if any answers prove me incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you fancy porting it to EE2.x then this plug-in might help with changing member group once a user already has already been registered.

```
{exp:change_member_group:change group_id="5"}
```

See: https://github.com/ninefour/change_member_group.pi.ee_addon

Answer (score 0):

Solspace User can allow members to change their member group. I have that setup on my site. I have two different member groups that people can register to be in - each with slightly different permissions. If they choose the wrong group when they register I provide the facility for them to switch their membership to the other group when they edit their account.